# How can I read json objects one at a time from a stream containing a json array without loading the whole array into memory?

Tags: json, go, stream

To reduce memory usage and reduce latency i want to start processing the json objects returned in a http response before they have all been sent.
I am trying to write a method on my web service client that will query a web service returning a channel that will feed the structs from the web request as the come off the stream.

```
    func (c *Client) GetMyObj() (<-chan models.MyObj, <-chan error) {
       outChan := make(chan models.MyObj)
       errChan := make(chan error)
       go func() {
          resp, err := httpClient.Get(c.ServiceUrl, "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", nil)
          if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
          }
          if resp.Status != "200 OK" {
             errChan <- fmt.Errorf("http error: %1", resp.Status)
             return
          }

          dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)

          for dec.More() {
             myO:= models.MyObj{}
             err := dec.Decode(&MyO)
             if err != nil {
                errChan <- err
                return
             }
             outChan <- dfe
          }           
       }()

       return outChan, errChan
    }
```

Unfortunately this produces an exception when it reads the preceding opening square bracket.The json document would look something like the below but with many more objects in the array and more properties on the object, but you get the idea:

```
    [{"name":"Value"}
    ,{"name":"Value"}
    ,{"name":"Value"}]
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder_Decode_stream (hint: `dec.Token`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the go documentation linked in the above comment provides example code that does exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example listed in the[`json.Decoder.Decode(...)` method documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode) shows exactly this.

In short, you do the following steps:

1. Read a token using `dec.Token()` (and optionally expect it to be an open square bracket)
2. Read tokens using `dec.Decode()` while `dec.More()`
3. Optionally, read the final closing square bracket.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/RrQXFfRKYti)):

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(jsonStream)
type Item struct{ Name string }

// Read the open bracket.
t, err := dec.Token()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("OK: %T: %v\n", t, t)

// While the array contains values.
for dec.More() {
    // Decode an array value.
    var item Item
    err := dec.Decode(&item)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("OK: item=%#v\n", item)
}

// Read the closing bracket.
t, err = dec.Token()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("OK: %T: %v\n", t, t)
// OK: json.Delim: [
// OK: item=main.Item{Name:"Value1"}
// OK: item=main.Item{Name:"Value2"}
// OK: item=main.Item{Name:"Value3"}
// OK: json.Delim: ]
```

Comment: I looked at Token(), it looked like it just kept reading from the stream until it found the closing bracket or brace for the first one it read, and adds all the read part to a buffer, if this is case it would read all of the response into memory which is what i was trying to avoid. I will dig back into Decoder to see if i have misunderstood.

Comment: looks like its using a buffered window rather than loading the whole lot, although what i cant tell from my experiment is if the window size is increasing by 512 bytes each cycle   https://play.golang.org/p/P7Wjj1aFrKk

Comment: even if it is that means it will only grow to just over 1MB whilst parsing a 1GB json file. could be a problem if im serving multiple request, i like to keep my Go services below the size of the configuration file for a spring-boot app ;)